# Checking 'check all' checkbox doesn't call p:ajax tag JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

ajax doesn't work when I check 'check all box' checkbox.

```
 <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="departmantCheckBox" value="#{marketAnalysisReportController.selectedDepartmants}"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:250px">
            <p:ajax update="saleCheckBox" listener="#{marketAnalysisReportController.updateSales}"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{marketAnalysisReportController.departmants}" var="departmant"
                            itemValue="#{departmant}"
                            itemLabel="#{departmant.name}"/>
        </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

Here's update method

```
public void updateSales(){
        sales=new ArrayList<Obje>();
        System.out.println("updatesales");
        for(Obje departmant: selectedDepartmants){
            System.out.println(departmant.name);
            if(departmant.getName().equals("test1")){
                sales.add(new Obje(20,"salestest20"));
                sales.add(new Obje(21,"salestest21"));
                System.out.println("add");
            }
            if(departmant.getName().equals("test2")){
                sales.add(new Obje(200,"salestest200"));
                sales.add(new Obje(210,"salestest210"));
            }
            if(departmant.getName().equals("test3")){
                sales.add(new Obje(250,"salestest250"));
                sales.add(new Obje(260,"salestest260"));
            }
            if(departmant==null || departmant.equals("")){
                sales=new ArrayList<Obje>();
            }
        }
    }
```

If I check boxes one by one, it works, but when I check 'check all checkboxes' it doesn't update sales. I can share more detail if you need.

Comment: You did not provide an explicit event, so it falls back to a default event. Did you check the documentation to see if there is another (non-default) event for the 'check all'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kukeltje allready pointed out the 'select all'- action does not fire the default ajax event which is caught by your  tag. The ajax event that is being fired when you select all is called 'toggleSelect', so you need to add another ajax tag like this:

> < p:ajax event="toggleSelect"...